# PHP Sum from a file

Tags: php, forms, file, sum, fopen

I'm here still learning to code with PHP, and I've got into one question at the moment.

I have a .txt file, say "results.txt" which contains 5 different options with a number behind. these represents like a voting from 5 different options. The layout is like this:

```
1|3
2|6
3|2
4|8
5|10
```

The ladder number is how many votes the options has got.

What I need to do is to sum the votes, increase it by 1 and then echo the result:

```
echo "Total votes: 30 votes"
```

Would be in this case.

The form which is used to voting is your normal and simple form with 5 different options:

```
<form action="aanestys.php" method="get">
Choose an option: 
<select name="vote">
<option value=1 selected>1</option> 
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">          
</form>
```

Do you have any tips or advice on how to do this? I don't necessarily need a straight answer because I do want to learn to use the fopen, fgets and fwrite commands and not just copy/paste codes.

Edit: It seems that the vote goes to an option which is selected with the form. And also that the .txt file must be up-to-date about it. So far I've got this:

```
<?php
$lines = file("results.txt");
$vote = $_GET['vote'];
$summa = 0;
$val = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
$var;
$var = explode("|", $line);
if ($vote == $var[0]){
    $var[1]++;
    array_push($val, $var[0], "|", $var[1]);
} else {
    array_push($val, $var[0], "|", $var[1]);
}
$summa = $summa += $var[1];
}
$ulos = implode("\n", $val) . "\n";
//Somehow, because this is an exercise, the checker says this is right 
//although it's totally not even close to it.

echo "Total votes: $summa votes.";

file_put_contents("results.txt", $ulos);
?>
```

But the vote count isn't right. What's wrong about this?

Comment: You want to increase the total of the one which is voted and then print the sum of all options votes?

Comment: No. I want to first sum all votes (29 in the example), then increase it by 1 (to 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file with [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), loop through the lines, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it with the delimiter "|", and store the sum in `$sum` by adding (`$var[1]`) everytime.

```
<?php
$lines = file('file.txt');
$sum = 0 ;

foreach ($lines as $line){
$var = explode("|", $line);
$sum = $sum +  $var[1];
}

echo $sum+1; //outputs 30
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This cleared things very well :) Nice explanation how this works and so on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some helper functions that are easier to use:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Further [implode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) are your friend.

Also [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) could be very helpful in your case.

Edit:

Do it like Robert, or another option with `fgetcsv` (didn't test it):

```
$sum = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("results.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $sum += (int) $data[1];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$sum += 1;
echo "Total votes: $sum votes";
```

If you need to increment specific votes you can do the following in the while loop:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = (int) $data[0];
    $vote = (int) $data[1];
    if ($num === 2) {
        $vote += 1;
    }
    else if ($num === 4) {
        $vote += 1;
    }
    $sum += $vote;
}
```

Comment: Any tips on how to separate the "1|" things from beginning so that I can sum the votes?

Comment: @user2466992 see my edit..I thought you want to do it by your own ;)

Comment: Just a quick question: What if the sum wasn't just increased by 1, but the increase would need to go on one of the vote counts?

Comment: @Uhkam see edit. in this example I increment the votes for num 2+4.

Comment: Mind looking at my edit in the question? I've got so close to it now but still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$text= file_get_contents('text.txt')` to read the text or `$text = file( 'text.txt' )` to read line by line 
 and put it in the variable $text.

Then use `split or explode with the delimiter |` to take just the second values then use `intval` to convert them from 
string to int, at the end you can sum them and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use function file() which puts the lines of file in array.

```
<?php 

$lines = file('results.txt');
$votes_up  = 0;
$votes_down = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) //loop after every line
{
  $votes = explode("|", $line); //exploding string by | param to get two votes
  $votes_up += $votes[0]; // it will ad first number as vote up
  $votes_down += $votes[1]; //same but for votes down
}

echo "total votes up: $votes_up<br>";
echo "total votes down: $votes_down<br>";
echo "total votes: ".($votes_up + $votes_down)."<br>";
echo "total votes + 1: ".($votes_up + $votes_down + 1)."<br>";

?>
```

Hope it helps you. In your case using `file()` is a lot better than fopen etc. However, in future if you need to handle file content you should pay attention to functions like:

- file_get_contents() - which gets content of file
- file_put_contents() - which puts the content to the file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fp=@fopen("results.txt","rb"); 
$sum = 0;
while($fp && $line=stream_get_line($fp,65535,"\n")){ 
    list($opt, $votes) = explode('|', trim($line)); 
    $sum += $votes;
} 
fclose($fp);
echo ++$sum;
```