# PHP - How can I make calculations with numbers I get from a text file?

Tags: php, sum, int, text-files, readfile

So I have a task where I should read a text file in php, containing students IDs and their grades, separated by vertical lines. It looks something like that:

```
12345|4|2|1|0|4 
45678|1|2|3|4|4 
78901|5|5|5|5|4
```

The program should print the amount of students there are on the file, which I managed to do by simply echoing the amount of lines. However, I should also print the sum of the grades for each student, and I simply can't find a way to do it. Do I get the characters by order on the line or something similar? I've been struggling with this for a day now and I only got as far as this:

```
<?php 

$file="exam.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}


echo "total_students was $linecount:";
$homepage = file_get_contents('exam.txt');
echo $homepage;


?>
```

This code only prints the page and the amount of lines, nothing more.

Comment: Side note: Is there a particular reason as to why you're not using a database for this? It would making counting/summing a lot easier, not to mention managing the data.

Comment: I'm completing an online course on PHP for my degree, and sadly the course is quite poorly written and the exercises sometimes get tricky. I have done the most part of the course by now, but this one really got me stuck and since it is online I can't really ask the tutors for help.

Comment: Ah, I see (and understand). Here's a Q&A that I found which may help you if you want to take a look at it and try something from it https://stackoverflow.com/q/17548443/1415724 - Which I found in a Google searching using the following keyword phrase: "sum values from a text file php" and contains more hits.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @RayA so why give an answer to something you downvoted? It doesn't make sense. If you feel the question is worth giving an answer, then it's either to upvote or don't vote at all, IMHO anyway. The OP did get that far on their own btw.

Comment: Well thank you for that, but I was definitely not asking you to write my homework. As you see, I was simply asking if there is an operator counting symbols on the file and stuff like that. If I wanted someone to "write my homework" I would simply copy paste the task the way it's written. If I wanted people to do my tasks I wouldn't even write here, I would just ask someone else doing the course to copy their answer.

Comment: Well, in this case, you made a valid point, I removed my down vote,

Comment: @RayA I take that that ^ was for me. It's always best to ping someone directly so that they know who the comment was for ;-)

Comment: hats off @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @n_at We support new coders and for the effort they put into wanting to do something, which I found you did do and probably didn't know what to look for (on the web). Try that Q&A link I gave you earlier and see if you can implement something from it and if you have any difficulties later, update your post under your original so that not to overwrite the original, and we'll take a look at it. Be sure to check for errors also with php's error reporting and using `var_dump($variable);` to see what's going through or not.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks man, I really appreciate it, Im gonna look into it right now.  Not knowing what to google is the exact problem I have, and it sucks when I get tasks on stuff that aren't explained at all in the course.

Comment: You're welcome @n_at Take your time and you'll get this. I've done something similar before but that was some time ago when I used to have to work with text files. When I started learning databases, is when everything made it much easier. But this is different for you and I understand. Good luck and enjoy :-)

Comment: A final note @n_at (if and) when you came up with a solution, Stack lets you post your own answer/solution which you can accept once it lets you. It's actually encouraged :-)

Answer (score 0):

So after I was guided in the right direction I managed to come up with a solution!

```
<?php 

$file="exam.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}


echo "total_students was $linecount:\n";


$lines = file('exam.txt');
$sum = 0 ;

foreach ($lines as $line){
$var = explode("|", $line);
$sum = $var[1]+$var[2]+$var[3]+$var[4]+$var[5];
$all += $sum;
echo "$var[0]: $sum points\n";
}

$average = $all / $linecount;
echo "The average score was $average points."

?>
```

I exploded each line as an array divided by the "|" symbol, then I printed the student ID from the [0] of the array, and summed the rest. After that I summed the sums and thus found the average.